# I am having problems compiling a code that includes .cu files compiled with nvcc and .cpp files compiled with gcc

Tags: gcc, cuda

I have a fairly large C++ code (over 60 separate files) and I am trying to switch some calculations to GPU using the CUDA-9 framework. The code normally compiles fine with gcc (v 7). Just as an exercise, I changed the extension of one of the source files from .cpp to .cu, WITHOUT changing any of the code in it. I ran make, which compiles the .cpp files with g++ and the .cu files with nvcc,  and I get an executable. However, when I ran the executable, I get almost immediately a seg fault. Needless to say, the code runs fine when compiled with gcc. In fact, it compiles and runs fine with the Intel compiler as well. These are the flags that are passed to the nvcc  compiler

nvcc -g  -Xcudafe  "--diag_suppress=code_is_unreachable" -Xcudafe "--diag_suppress=extra_semicolon"

while the flags to g++ are

g++ -fPIC -O3 -g -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-comment -Wno-maybe-uninitialized     -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-long -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-deprecated 
-ftemplate-depth-39 -Wno-variadic-maris -m64

Due to the size of the code, I would like to avoid having to rename all files to .cu. Moreover, it depends on libraries that have been compiled with gcc, so that switching the entire problem to nvcc is unpractical, not to mention the fact that nvcc seems to be very slow compared to gcc. The symbolic link in cuda-9.0/bin for gcc points to gcc-7. I also tried to add the switch --device-c to nvcc, but in this case it won't link...
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention: it does not matter which of the files get changed to .cu. The only difference is in the nature of the error. Sometime a segfault, other times it triggers asserts in the file with the .cu extension that should not be triggered. The whole thing smells of a corrupted stack when object files from nvcc and g++ are linked together...

Comment: The flags that you show being passed to `nvcc` include `--device-c`.  Confusing.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The code compiles (but segfaults), without the --device-c flag. I have fixed it in the main test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely sounds like a linking issue. Have a look here for comprehensive instructions on linking cuda device code with c++ code: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/

Unfortunately you didn't provide your linking commands. I'll try to make my suggestions as general as possible. The short of it is that only nvcc understands how to link device code to CPU object code, so it needs to be involved in the linking process, not just as a compiler. Have a look at the "Using Device Code Linking" and the "Advanced Usage: Using a Different Linker" sections in the link above. You can either use nvcc as the compiler and linker, or you can use nvcc to link together a combined cpu- and device-code object file using the -dlink option, and then you can link everything together normally. In both cases you should pass the -dc option to nvcc when you compile source files containing device code (this indicates that you want to link together the device code later)

Note also that nvcc can compile .cpp files; by default it will assume .cpp files contain only cpu-code. You don't need to rename your cpu-only source files to compile them with nvcc.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the post, which I will study. Also good to know that nvcc can compile regular .cpp code. I guess I should try first to compile and link the whole code with nvcc and report. What c++ compiler does nvcc fall back on? I am asking because it gave me some warnings that I do not get using g++ (mostly related to SFINAE situations).

Comment: Ok, I tweaked the Makefile to use nvcc both for .cpp and .cu files, though at this moment there are only .cpp files. Everything compiled fine, but, oddly enough, I had to use g++ to link the files. Using nvcc (on object files generated by nvcc) I got a ton of "warning: null character(s) ignored" and at the end "error: unterminated comment." The command used for linking was nvcc -g -x cu *.o -l<bunch of libraries> -o main. As I said, using g++ produced an executable that runs fine. Next, I will try to compile code that actually involves device functions